# Proving by induction that $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{n}{2}+1$ holds for all $n \ge 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, summation, induction, harmonic-numbers

While looking at some examples of proof by induction related to inequalities, I had this one that I didn't quite get:

> Prove by induction that the following holds for all $n \ge 1$:
>
> $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{n}{2}+1$$
>
> ---
>
> We have to prove that it holds for $n + 1$, that is:
>
> $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n + 1}\le\frac{n
> > + 1}{2}+1$$
>
> ---
>
> Hypothesis:
>
> $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{n}{2}+1$$
>
> ---
>
> To prove this, we have to prove two things:
>
> $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+1}\le\frac{n}{2}+1+\frac{1}{n+1}$$
>
> $$\textrm{and}$$
>
> $$\frac{n}{2}+1+\frac{1}{n+1}\le \frac{n + 1}{2}+1$$
>
> ---
>
> $$\textrm{* Proof goes here *}$$

My problem is with the "we have to prove these two things" part. I can see how proving them would effectively prove the whole thing, since we're trying to prove that $A \le C$, it would be the same as proving that $A \le B \land B \le C$, which seems to be what they are doing. However, **under what reasoning did they decide that $B$ should be $\frac{n}{2}+1+\frac{1}{n+1}$?** Was that **the** value necessary for $B$, or could it have been something else?

Comment: The value of $B$ is followed by hypothesis

Comment: The induction hypothesis says that the sum up to $1/n$ is $\le n/2 +1$. So the sum up to $1/(n+1)$ is $\le n/2+1 +1/(n+1)$. And of course this is $\le (n+1)/2+1$, since $1/(n+1)\le 1/2$.

Comment: It could have been something else, perhaps, but they chose that value because it fit their own version of the proof the best.

Comment: ?? Haven't they simply added 1/n+1 to both sides of the hypothesis statement. Why is it so magical to you?

Comment: @TenaliRaman: I know what they did, I don't know why, of all options, they had to choose that one. They could've added *something else* to both sides too, right? Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably better to read that as "to prove this *using the method below*, we have to prove two things...."

Using a proof method that starts by proving that particular $A \leq B$ is a fairly natural choice in this particular instance, since it follows trivially from the inductive hypothesis, and the right hand side appears simpler than the left hand side.

Answer (score 2):

First, check the base case $n = 1$ (trivial). Then for the inductive step, assume that the statement holds for $n = k$, that is, assume $H_k \leq k/2 + 1$, where $H_k$ is the $k$th harmonic number. Then use the inductive hypothesis to prove that $H_n \leq n/2 + 1$ also holds for $n = k + 1$. In other words,
$$H_k + \frac{1}{k + 1} \leq \frac{k + 1}{2} + 1$$
is the inequality you need to prove. But this is equivalent to the first "thing" by the inductive hypothesis: just add $1/(k + 1)$ to both sides of
$$H_k \leq \frac{k}{2} + 1.$$
Now you simply need to prove the second "thing" i.e. $B \leq C$ with $B = k/2 + 1 + 1/(k + 1)$ and $C = (k + 1)/2 + 1$ and you are done.

Comment: It would be better for showing what B is. :)